Switch between notations for factorial
I am working with an old textbook where the factorial of $n$ is denoted by $\varPi(n)$. I would like to make a document where one can choose in the preamble whether to use this notation or the usual one $n!$. So I wrote two lines in the preamble, one of which should be commented out:
%\newcommand{\fac}[1]{{#1}!}
\newcommand{\fac}[1]{\varPi(#1)}

I didn’t realise immediately that I run into trouble with this scheme; for if I write
\fac{n+1}

This gives $\varPi(n+1)$ in one notation, but $n+1!$ in the other, which is bad. Conversely, if you add brackets
\fac{(n+1)}

You get a pair of brackets too many in $\varPi((n+1))$.
Any suggestions for how to solve this?
Edit: Following a suggestion (that has since been deleted) I started thinking along the following lines: I could write \fac{expr} for anything that works in both versions and add an extra pair of {} (or another kind of token) around the expression if I need an extra pair of brackets in the !-notation. Of course that would have to be parsed, and I currently don’t have the knowledge to do so.

No idea why $…$ isn’t turned into LaTeX …

mathjax is not supported on this site (as it doesn't use tex) if you want to show tex output, insert an image

@DavidCarlisle Thanks!

Here I first check whether \ifoldfactorial returns true (by default it returns false) and in this case \fac{<symbols>} produces \varpi(<symbols>}.
When \ifoldfactorial is false, I check whether <symbols> is a single character or a string of digits and in this case output <symbols>!; otherwise parentheses are added.
The example below sets \ifoldfactorial mid-document just for testing. For a normal document you just enable or disable \oldfactorialtrue.
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifoldfactorial

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fac}{m}
 {
  \legacy_if:nTF { oldfactorial }
   {% old style
    \varpi(#1)
   }
   {% modern style
    \tom_factorial:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tom_factorial:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {% just one token
    #1!
   }
   {% else, we need more
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A (?:[[:digit:]]* | ._. | ._\{[^\}]*\}) \Z } { #1 }
     {% only digits
      #1!
     }
     {% parentheses needed
      (#1)!
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{Modern notation}\par\medskip

$\fac{0}+\fac{1}+\fac{11}+\fac{n}+\fac{n+1}$

$\fac{n_k}+\fac{n_{k+1}}$

$\fac{\alpha_1}+\fac{\alpha_{12}}+\fac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$

\bigskip

\textbf{Older notation}\par\medskip
\oldfactorialtrue

$\fac{0}+\fac{1}+\fac{11}+\fac{n}+\fac{n+1}$

$\fac{n_k}+\fac{n_{k+1}}$

$\fac{\alpha_1}+\fac{\alpha_{12}}+\fac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$

\end{document}



Works like a charm, thank you! I wasn’t aware of this LaTeX3 style of programming. Can you point me to a good manual to learn to use it?

I ran into a situation where it still doesn’t work as intended: when I use \tom_factorial{\alpha_1}, LaTeX puts brackets around the \alpha_1. Can you tweak your code to solve this?

@tomdeneckere Added more tests

@tomdeneckere To learn LaTeX3, you can look for example at www.texdev.net. The main documentation is The LaTeX3 Interface.

Thanks! And thanks for the references.
